# Security Analysis: Adversary's Ability to Recover Concatenated and Hashed Secret with Partial String Knowledge

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, keys

Suppose I have the following secret, calculated by concatenating and hashing the results of two random strings:

secret = H( H( random_string1 ) || H( random_string2 ) )

Let's assume that the adversary knows one of these strings but not the other. In this case, can the adversary recover the secret in a practical manner?

Assume that H is a secure hash function like SHA-256.

Comment: Look into [prefix MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41733/equivalence-of-secret-iv-and-secret-prefix-mac) and [suffix MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5725/why-is-hmk-insecure/5750). That's essentially what you're describing, just you're hashing the key and message.